# How to stop Windows Server 2022 successful anomymous RDP logins

Tags: windows, security, rdp

I have a Windows Server 2022 server with IPBAN installed to make hacking it more difficult but in the logs occasionally I see:

```
2023-02-20 03:59:23.5304|WARN|IPBan|Login succeeded, address: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, user name: ANONYMOUS LOGON, source: RDP
```

I've been searching and found that this is most likely harmless is this correct?

Also how do I replicate and prevent these logins?

Comment: Did you even bother to check the logs on the target host?

Comment: This is from the target host...

Comment: I'm referring to the security logs. That have information about authentication.